# Accessing an class attribute from subclass (Python)?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, subclass

Here is the format of my code:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, x, other):
        self.other = other
        self.x = x
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        # place code here
    def something_else(self):
        return self.x["foo"]
```

`x` is an object which I would like to call, with a subscript later on (in `something_else`.

I would like only `x` to be inherited from the parent class.
It is important that `other` is not inherited, so `super().__init__` is not suitable.

I have attempted a workaround by creating a function within `class A`:

```
def x(self):
    return self.x
```

so I could call `super().x()` in `class B`, but this doesn't work either.

I have attempted calling directly `super.x["foo"]`, and this doesn't work.

How can I achieve what I want in my case?
Thanks!

Comment: If you want to *not* inherit something, your class hierarchy is wrong.

Comment: Still, in the case where I inherit the entire x function (see second block of code), subscripting it does not work as expected.

Comment: What are you expecting to obtain when you subscript a function?  It's not a subscriptable object.

Comment: Why is it a problem that `other` is inherited? If you don't want to use it, can't you just ignore it?

Comment: @Prune This is exactly my problem, I would like to subscript `self.x` as defined in A.__init__().

Comment: @mkrieger1, `other` calls a method which takes a lot of time to run, so this is not an option.

Comment: You fail to give the expected use case, but you *say* that `x` is a function.  Functions are not subscriptable objects.

Comment: @Prune, no, `self.x` is an object from another library. I created a function `x`, returning `self.x`, so that (maybe) I'd be able to pass it over to `B`.

Comment: You already have an attribute `x` in the class; you can't create another in this fashion.

Comment: Also, the only way to keep `other` from being inherited is to not create it in the parent class.  This is part of the definition of sub-class inheritance.

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  Your disjointed description isn't quite enough to define your intended use case.

Answer (score 1):

Variables don't always have to be registered in the `__init__` function, if you want `x` from class `A`, have a method in `A`:

```
def set_x(self, x):
    self.x = x
    # other stuff
```

you'll still be able to call `set_x` from class `B` as all functions are inherited, from there you can instantiate property `x` without calling `__init__` from `A`.

Comment: I am not entirely sure we are on the same page, could you please elaborate?
When I set up an `A` object, I want to pass `x` directly in there, as `x` is used by the rest of the code in A.__init__() as well.

Comment: Well, since you can't use `__init__` function in `A`, just have a different function in `A` to set `x`, and then after you instantiated a instance of B, you can call `self.set_x()` from your `B.__init__()` since the function is inherited.